# How to convert <text> (text tag) to anchor tag in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have one `<text>` tag which contains plain text but I want to show a hyperlink instead of plain text.

```
      <svg width="800" height="600" class="overlay">
<g transform="translate(100,220)">
<path class="link" d="M80,120C120,120 120,106.66666666666666 160,106.66666666666666"></path>
<path class="link" d="M80,120C120,120 120,133.33333333333334 160,133.33333333333334"></path>
<path class="link" d="M80,40C120,40 120,26.666666666666686 160,26.666666666666686"></path>
<path class="link" d="M80,40C120,40 120,53.333333333333314 160,53.333333333333314"></path>
<path class="link" d="M0,80C40,80 40,40 80,40"></path><path class="link" d="M0,80C40,80 40,120 80,120"></path><g class="node" transform="translate(160,133.3333282470703)">
<circle class="nodeCircle" r="8" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></circle><text x="13" dy=".35em" class="hyper" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;">Tiger</text>
```

In above code, lion comes as plain text but I want to show up one hyperlink.

I have tried to do it with `.attr()` but it's not working.

Comment: What exactly is this? Coz this is not a HTML right?

Comment: text is custom tag here

Comment: Lemme try to change using jQuery. It is possible. But where's the link to?

Comment: I just want to convert this text tag with anchor tag..is it possible ?

Comment: Have a look at my answer? I am not sure what to put inside the `href=""` of it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`replaceWith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/):

```js
$(function () {
  $("text").each(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith('<a href="">' + $(this).html() + '</a>');
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<text x="13" dy=".35em" class="hyper" text-anchor="start" style="fill-opacity: 1;">Lion</text>
```

I am not sure what to put for `href` attribute, but if you need, you can put something yourself, by editing the function.

Comment: @Pravin Kumar : can just replace content with anchor tag ? coz I have tried above code, its working but showing nothing on the page

Comment: Are you adding it inside the `$(document)` ready function? Can you share the full code?

Comment: @Akki, call me `Praveen` not `Pravin` `:P`. Hey, are you trying to convert the `SVG` code? How are you running it? How are you including it in the HTML?

Comment: "@Praveen" :) I have included D3 library and its rendering from that library  and thats why I am not able to add anchor at the time of creation

Comment: @Akki Ha! There you go!!! That could be a problem. Sorry to bother you, but could you create a working fiddle out of your code using **http://jsbin.com**, please?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`replacewith`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
$('text').replaceWith('<a href="http://example.com">link</a>')
```